# "make" and "do" - how to make sure you take the right one?

Tags: word-choice, do-vs-make

I learned the simplified rule that *make* is used when I create something and *do* when I, well, do tasks. There's another question here [about make versus do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10534/138) and its answer seconds that.

On the other hand, in any dictionary you also find a definition that basically states that *do* can be used in the sense of *make*:

> to produce or make something

So, I'm looking for some more thorough explanation on when to choose *make* and when *do*. The simplified view at the matter will make me make the right choice most often but not always.

Just a few examples:

> You *make a speech* and *you make jokes* but you *do small talk*.
>   You *make the bed* and you *make the table* but you *do the flowers*, *do the dishes* and *do your homework*.

How can I decide which word to use. Let's say I'd like to figure out if I *make* or *do* a copy of something.
*Make a copy* has certainly more hits, but in my book this is like *doing homework*. When I do my homework, I just write some words on a paper. When I copy my homework, I make sure the same is written on another paper. In both cases I *do something* but also in both cases I *create something* (not physically).

So, what are the clues that help me find the right word (in general, not only restricted to the previous example)?

Comment: I don't agree with your data. I think you make small talk (just like a speech, or jokes).  I don't know what "do the flowers" means. "Do the dishes" is correct, but it refers to cleaning them, not to creating them, so it is consistent with your earlier rule.

Comment: @hunter "Make small talk" was what I had said before I wrote this question, but my research while writing made me change my opinion on that. And according to my dictionary "do the dishes" means "to arrange".

Comment: @hunter is right: you "make" small talk, and *do the dishes*, at least in the US, means to wash them. Also (and again, in US use), you don't "make" the table unless you're a carpenter: if you're arranging the plates and silverware you "set" the table.

Comment: I think your simplified rule is correct almost all the time (use *make* only when you can think of it in the sense of *creating it* or *producing it*, otherwise, use *do*). Being a learner, I think the best way is to stick with the rule, and make a note on exceptions we find, which I think there are only a handful of them. Also note that sometimes we have both usages, e.g. *make her own bed* vs. *I'll join you after I've done the beds*.

Comment: But I'm pretty antisocial. I don't do small talk.

Comment: @toandfro: I bet you don't do drugs, either. But be honest - do you *take* drugs?

Comment: @em1: I'm pretty sure I've never come across *"do the dishes"* used to mean *"**arrange** the dishes"*. What dictionary are you using? I think you should get rid of it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: No, I only make drugs. I am Heisenberg.

Comment: @FumbleFingers According to OALD, "do the dishes" means "to wash" them, but "do the flowers" is "to arrange" them.

Comment: @em1: It's all context-dependant. The general form *do the X* just means *attend to X / perform whatever actions are necessary in respect of X*. In some contexts, it's necessary that X should be *created*, in which case most likely *do* and *make* can be used interchangeably.

Comment: "Do the flowers" is not a phrase in my American dialect.  "Do the dishes" (wash them) and "Do homework" absolutely, not not flowers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid the only general distinction is the one you have already named: *do* = *perform* and *make = create*.

But that is no more than a general tendency; as your examples show, in any specific instance either or both may be relevant, and at some point in the history of the language one has earned more favour than the other.

It's often possible to see a reason why one is used rather than the other in a particular situation, and that's useful for *remembering* which one is used; but it is of no value in *predicting* which one is used when you encounter a new situation. For instance:

> You complete your homework assignments, which included writing down the answers to a series of questions. It seems that should be 'making' your homework, but in fact the proper phrase is *doing your homework*. You might remember this by considering that sometimes your homework doesn't call for you to 'make' anything: it might be reading a chapter in your textbook. The important thing is you *did* the tasks that were assigned.
>
> You agree to act as the fourth person in a game of contract bridge. You would think this would call for 'do', since you are performing a role; but in fact you *make a fourth*. You can remember this by noting that what you are doing is “making” a complete table of players—would that have occurred to you before you encountered the phrase?

There's just no telling. You have to learn the right term case by case.

Comment: I wouldn't want to get bogged down in an endless list of "ambivalent" usages - but for me at least, *make the dinner* and *do the dinner*, for example, are pretty much interchangeable variants of *prepare the dinner*. I also think it might be *slightly* more useful to think in terms of the *do/make* choice being more dependent on whether the primary focus is on *action/result*. And the "predictive value" may be less than 100% reliable, but it's certainly significantly higher than a "by chance" 50%, so things aren't *quite* as bad as your final paragraph suggests.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, sure; it's probably around 2:1 - but if you're writing something important do you roll the dice for a 67% chance, or do you take the time to look it up and have 100% chance of getting it right?

Comment: If I write anything "important" these days, it's always on the computer - so a quick check is usually easy. But I imagine I'm much the same as everyone else - nearly all my language production is *spoken* (and relatively trivial, at that). To a considerable extent I think learning the "correct" use of prepositions, etc., is like learning a route used to be before satnavs. If it was *vital* I didn't take a wrong turn on any single occasion, I'd check it all out on the map first. Otherwise, I'd just "follow my nose", and only bother to learn those junctions where that approach didn't work.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right. But your nose is informed by several decades of immersion in the language. I'd be surprised if you had to travel an unfamiliar route of this sort once a year; and if you did, you'd know another way to get there. That's not the case with our learners.

Comment: @StoneyB In your answer you agreed that "to make" equals "to create". However, it just came to my attention that — from an English perspective — this isn't really true. There are just a very few examples where this is the case, like "to make products". Usually, "to make" is rather in the sense of "to achieve", e.g. "to make the team", "to make money", or "to make sure". Or in the phrase "to make sense" it's more about "It's meaningful" rather than "to create meaning". That being said, understanding this matter doesn't explain why you "make the table" but "do the flowers". I'm wondering....

Comment: ....if you as a native English speaker — and if I'm not mistaken also sophisticated in (English) language history — can see any conclusion to the question at hand, based on the understanding that "make" is actually not equal to "create"? — On a side note, I read an article about the verbatim translation "to make sense" into German ("Sinn machen") and a discussion about why the German translation is completely amiss, based on the fact that the German "machen" in fact is a false friend to "make". This seems to be the cause why it's hard to grasp the meaning of "to make".

Comment: @Em1 I did not agree that "to make" equals "to create" -- I said that the contrast between "do" and "make" **tends** to split along the 'perform'/'create' axis, but that that is no more than a tendency. In all of your examples 'create'--to cause something to be the case or come into existence which was not the case or in existence before--is a better approximation of the semantic domain of 'make' than 'perform' would be.